# ScriptSharp 0.7.1 and AjaxRequestCallback<object> compilation fails

Tags: script#

I'm attempting to upgrade my version of ScriptSharp from 0.6.2 to 0.7.1 to take advantage of the new generics feature. The last issue I have come across that I don't know how to solve is this: when making an Ajax call, the compiler fails with the message "Check that your C# source compiles and that you are not using an unsupported feature".

Here's the code:

```
jQuery.Ajax(
            new jQueryAjaxOptions(
                "url", url,
                "type", "GET",
                "dataType", "html",
                "contentType", "application/json",
                "processData", false,
                "success", (AjaxRequestCallback<object>)delegate(object result, string textData, jQueryXmlHttpRequest<object> XMLHttpRequest)
                {
                    container.Html(XMLHttpRequest.ResponseText);

                    Type.InvokeMethod(null, "ajaxUnBlock", null);
                },
                "error", (AjaxErrorCallback<object>)delegate(jQueryXmlHttpRequest<object> request, string textData, Exception e)
                {
                    //Debug.TraceDump(XMLHttpRequest);
                }
            )
        );
```

I know it's the delegates which are causing this. If I was to instead populate the properties of jQueryAjaxOptions (as opposed to providing a dictionary of key/values) then when I double-click the error in the error window it points me to the line which specifies the success delegate.

I seem to be able to work around it by creating a method instead of using an anonymous delegate and the compiler error goes away, but I would like to avoid going down that road if at all possible as I have a large amount of code which would have to be converted in this way.

Has anyone had experience with this and can let me know why this happens and is there anything I can do to get my anonymous delegates to compile again?

Many thanks in advance

**Edit**
Making the function which contains this anonymous delegate **static** fixes the issue. While researching this issue I found a closed issue on Github (https://github.com/NikhilK/scriptsharp/issues/22) which seems related - the only thing I'm unsure of now is whether this behaviour is intended or not.